# Use instanceof to check if some variable is class constructor type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function, which receives a constructor with its parameter and creates an instance with that constructor. I have to check the constructor's type, but when I tried to check it, it shows an error.

These are some codes I've already tried.

I tried this:

```js
function hello(arg: Function) {
  if(arg instanceof typeof MyClass) { // .. constructor(a: number) ..
    return new arg(123)
  } else if(arg instanceof typeof MyClass2) { // .. constructor(a: string) ..
    return new arg('abc')
  } else return arg(true)
}
```

but this shows this error:

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.  ts(2359)

I also tried this:

```js
// ...
if (arg.prototype instanceof Component) {
  const hi = new arg(123)
  // ...
}
```

but:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.  ts(2351)

I want to check some constructor's type, like:

```js
hello(MyClass) // new MyClass(123)
hello(MyClass2) // new MyClass2('abc')
```

Comment: why are you using typeof?

Comment: @Fallenreaper It was just experimental and I expected 'typeof MyClass' to be type of the constructor of MyClass.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Typescript, constructor functions are part of classes. The Typescript compiler will produce Javascript "constructor" functions (for ES5 or earlier) or for more recent versions of ECMAScript, the generated JavaScript will retain the `class` keyword.

The example below was inspired by the Typescript handbook section on [**instanceof type guards**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards).

Rather than creating a function that accepts a constructor function parameter, the function **`instantiateClass`** accepts a Typescript class, which is then instantiated and returned based on the run-time type.

## Example Typescript Function accepting a Class to be Instantiated

```
interface Padder {
    getPaddingString(): string
}

class SpaceRepeatingPadder implements Padder {
    constructor(private numSpaces: number) { }
    getPaddingString() {
        return Array(this.numSpaces + 1).join(" ");
    }
}

class StringPadder implements Padder {
    constructor(private value: string) { }
    getPaddingString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

function instantiateClass(myClass: new (...args: any[]) => any): Padder {
    if (myClass instanceof SpaceRepeatingPadder) {
        return new myClass(2 /* numSpaces */);
    } else if (myClass instanceof StringPadder) {
        return new myClass('*' /* value */);
    } else {
        return new myClass()
    }
}

let padder = instantiateClass(SpaceRepeatingPadder);
if (padder instanceof SpaceRepeatingPadder) {
    console.log("type narrowed to 'SpaceRepeatingPadder'")
}
if (padder instanceof StringPadder) {
    console.log("type narrowed to 'StringPadder'")
}

padder = instantiateClass(StringPadder);
if (padder instanceof SpaceRepeatingPadder) {
    console.log("type narrowed to 'SpaceRepeatingPadder'")
}
if (padder instanceof StringPadder) {
    console.log("type narrowed to 'StringPadder'")
}
```

#### Console Output

```
type narrowed to 'SpaceRepeatingPadder'
type narrowed to 'StringPadder'
```

See example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwCYesg3gWAChkTkBzCMdLUMgZTCloAoBKALmQGdHaiBfIkQQAbOFy7I6AB0QQAShGkQ4YWtWxRkwALbSREHRHCSNOAsVIIA9iB5QArgjDWozaUwBuqlCAc6ZOS5OPx0AI2hWPGRBSxIKKkwMWgYmEDI2PCJSHOQoSgcoEGQAQSgoOABPZjAAC2AuADpQwKRJAGpkAEZWRoAra1BmACJkYdYAbmzSWNjhMQkpXnSzLV19Q2MwUyTzaZIbO0YnFzcPYG9IZG8RBwhOe1oo3Bj98koNFOWM57ec-LAhWKdQajRudymcVehDmhBgDhAzmAtm0Rzg4GAPgAwgsuMwdJUceJgsgQBAAO7IZiNGlwKBkEnoyoAbQAulEALwAPmQTI4aF2WgsOWAMCpBKJi1APHRSGsYtaCiUKjUK0Fvyh-wKRVJFOQEtxzAATMgAPQAKlJ-kVknNpsmb34yAgIi4KFF4sJuNRMsREHlSzSZFWGtypABQN1lINxOYAHJzXGzZbwSg7Q6oU6XW6sprw9rimTo17Y6xHQIhIQDGBkLIsDgOT6wOi1NjDYrFMpVOp1ZCPe5BU3Zf6FbIkJ2VT361BQ1ZbFxrAZGiJrBlhmBKspSXSoNZyRAMMgXMg4x3ld21dO4+MK4R+3XNEO-QHUlPNLODvPFxBl6uRhutxAHc9wPI9rBPV9L00a8yxhSsHwbJ9W0gSU8Ug4NeyIe9B2lZtn1HOQJwvDDpw-ZBDgXJcVzXADfGA-dD2PU8xyVLtVRI6Cbzgu8xQHacnzlBVvhDXMcgo79fxozc6PKEDGPA09hMFGDbyIIA)

In the Playground under <kbd>Options</kbd>, try changing target version of ECMAScript.

Comment: Then, how can I check if some variable is instance of `new (...args: any[]) => any`? (= how can I check if some function is the constructor of a class?)

Comment: The type definition `new (...args: any[]) => any` matches any Type whose constructor requires being called with the `new` keyword. What we're checking is which *Class* the variable is an `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following classes:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(public a: number) {}
}

class MyClass2 {
  constructor(public a: string) {}
}
```

I would create a factory function as follows:

```
function classFactory<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(arg: T): InstanceType<T> {
   if (arg instanceof MyClass) {
      // .. constructor(a: number) ..
      return new arg(123);
   } else if (arg instanceof MyClass2) {
      // .. constructor(a: string) ..
      return new arg("abc");
   } else return new arg(true);
}
```

*[InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is one of the builtin utility types.*

---

Usage would look something like:

```
const obj = classFactory(MyClass); // type = MyClass
```